# Using Blazor (i.e. WebAssembly) + javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, webassembly, blazor

Im really excited at what WebAssembly can bring to us web UI developers.
Now correct me if im wrong, but a web assembly / blazor project can easily and happily coexist with javascript. The script might handle all the http web requests and various clientside manipulations.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could do that, as of version 0.4 it is easy to interop between c# and javascript and vise versa.

But you don't have to, the beauty of blazor is that you can just use the `HttpClient` class from .net framework `System.Net.Http` namespace for calls to your backend.
And make razor `cshtml` components for DOM manipulation.

[More on http calls from blazor](http://learn-blazor.com/architecture/rest-api/)

[More on js interop](http://learn-blazor.com/architecture/interop/)

Comment: This means during run-time the browser will make httprequests (from the webassembly)?

Comment: Yes. Webassembly will use the browser for httprequests. It's running in the same sandbox as javascript.

Comment: Cool, will the browser be able to capture the network traffic (i.e. F12) for Webassembly invoked httprequests)?